# Does Google Docs support variables?

Tags: google-docs

Similar to Microsoft Word **DocProperties** where you're able to use update a DocProperty value as metadata, and its value gets update in the whole document.

Does Google Docs have something similar?

(I'm planning on modifying said variable's value programmatically from the outside of the document via a script.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, Google Documents, Spreadsheets and Forms have something similar -> [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/), and more specifically the [properties class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties).

## Explanation

The extension mechanism for Google Documents, Spreadsheets and Forms is Google Apps Script. See the following guide: [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs)

Comment: Is there a way to call a **bound** script's method using the execution API, or similar? I want to change the data of the document property from the outside (my php app)

Comment: That was already asked on [so]. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494631/calling-a-bound-scripts-method-using-the-execution-api